# Prove that $\pm 5, \pm 5^2 ,...,\pm5^{2^{a-2}}$ forms a reduced residue system mod $2^a$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

> Let $a \ge 3$ Prove that $\pm 5, \pm 5^2 ,...,\pm5^{2^{a-2}}$ forms a reduced residue system mod $2^a$

**My attempt:** We are given $\phi(2^a) = 2^{a-1} $number of elements, hence this is a possible candidate for a reduced residue system( **$\phi$ denotes the Euler totient function**). I approached this problem by Induction. For $a=3$, $\,\, \pm 5, \pm 5^2 \equiv 1,3,5,7 \bmod(8)$, which is clearly a reduced residue system $\bmod (2^3)$.

But after assuming it for $a=k$, for some $k>3$, I am not able to see how this holds for $a=k+1$. Am I on the right track? Is there any other way to solve this problem?

Comment: Can you show that $5$ has multiplicative order $2^{a-2}$ over the integers modulo $2^a$?

Comment: https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://cameroncounts.wordpress.com/2014/01/09/primitive-lambda-roots/amp/&ved=2ahUKEwjch7-otbrkAhWLpo8KHYYzASAQFjACegQIAxAB&usg=AOvVaw0idU3EvAYGhBMw8ZmqGk6D&ampcf=1

Comment: i can write $5^{2^{a-3}} \equiv (1+4)^{2^{a-3}} \equiv 1+2^{a-1} \bmod (2^a) $. If i square both sides, it gives me $5^{2^{a-2}}  \equiv 1+2^{a}+2^{2(a-1)} \equiv 1+2^{2(a-1)} \bmod (2^a) $, and since $a\ge 3$ it gives  $5^{2^{a-2}}  \equiv 1 \bmod (2^a)$

Comment: You're halfway there. Now suppose you have the set $\{\pm5,\ldots,\pm5^{2^{a-2}}\}$. How many elements does this set have ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**:

Prove by induction that $\; 5^{2^k}\equiv 1+2^{k+2}\mod 2^{k+3}$, and deduce that

1. The congruence class has order $2^{a-2}\mod 2^a$,
2. The subgroups  $\bigl\langle\,\overline 5\,\bigr\rangle$ and   $\bigl\langle\,\overline{\mkern-4mu -1}\,\bigr\rangle$ have a trivial intersection, whence $\;\mathbf Z/2^a\mathbf Z$  is the product of these two subgroups.